# How to find the remainder of division that satisfies a condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking for a simple way to find the number c that making the (a+c) is divisibility b. For example, if `a=12, b =4`, then `c =0`. If `a=13, b=4` then `c=3`

This is my code but it does not work well

```
a =12
b = 4
if (a % b):
  c =0
else:
  c = b - a % b
print (c)
```

Sorry if my question is too simple.

Comment: With what numbers does it not work well?

Comment: Result of the first case is not correct. This is output https://repl.it/repls/TiredGratefulInformation

Comment: You got the comparison the wrong way around.

Comment: Thanks, Actually, I want to make it without the condition if. Is it possible?

Comment: `(b - a % b) % b`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's probably a simpler way, but this works:

```
c = (b - a % b) % b
```

Answer (score 1):

```
c = -a % b
```

You'd need something more complicated in languages like C, where `%` matches the sign of the left operand instead of the right.

Comment: This is also tricky with `decimal.Decimal`, where the same problem happens.